# Как спозиционировать блоки навигации при разном количестве буллетов?

Tags: html, css, slider, позиционирование, навигация

Есть на сайте слайдер [LayerSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246) в котором хочу кнопки со стрелками навигации спозиционировать в правом нижнем углу независимо от количества слайдов, а значит и количества буллетов и при любом разрешении экрана так, чтобы не было между блоками просветов, не наезжали друг на друга - как это можно реализовать? 
**ВАЖНО: без правки `html`!**
при фиксированном количестве слайдов набросал [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/h54336ng/)

```css
.ls-nav-prev {
  position: absolute;
  right: 87px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.ls-nav-prev:before {
  content: "\f104";
  display: block;
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.ls-nav-next {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.ls-nav-next:before {
  content: "\f105";
  display: block;
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
.ls-bottom-slidebuttons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: auto;
  padding: 12px;
}
.ls-bottom-slidebuttons>a:before {
  content: "\f111";
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="list1">
  <a class="ls-nav-prev" href="#" style="visibility: visible;"></a>
  <a class="ls-nav-next" href="#" style="visibility: visible;"></a>
  <div>
    <span class="ls-bottom-slidebuttons">
<a href="#" class=""></a>
<a href="#" class="ls-nav-active"></a>
</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: вряд ли ваш вопрос понятен, сейчас ничего не разъезжается же, в чем вопрос?

Comment: @Jean-Claude вопрос состоит в том, чтобы спозиционировать элементы  **независимо от количества слайдов**, т.е. попробуйте добавить ссылки в блок `<span class="ls-bottom-slidebuttons">`

Comment: ну так как вы собираетесь вставлять произвольное кол-во ссылок-кружков если стрелка левая с фиксированным значением отступа right: 87px; ? бредок вопрос, стрелки надо внутрь блока ls-bottom-slidebuttons закинуть, вот и все дела.

Comment: @Jean-Claude я же русским по белому написал, что сделал для фикс количества элементов, а спрашиваю как сделать для произвольного количества... как вы думаете зачем я указал и выделил жирным **ВАЖНО: без правки html!** спроста чтоль??